# which approach for readability classifier

Tags: java, weka, svm, classification

I'm afraid my understanding of the theory behind classifiers is not deep, so please excuse me if my question looks naive to you.

**Goal:**
Given an arbitrary text, classify it according to age ranges, that is according to its readability. So my classes will be age ranges like (simplified): 5-6, 6-8, 8-10, 10-14, 14-16, adult.
Ideally, each text document should get a probability for each of those classes (not only the most likely class).

**Current state:**
A feature extractor is in place. It outputs a feature vector per text document, with about 30 features, almost all numeric, a couple of them are nominal.
I am experimenting with training a model with Weka, for now using the SMO svm included in weka, optimized with grid search. I could also use libSVM, but this isn't important for now.

**Questions:**

1. Would you use a different classifier for this task, especially wrt the desired output with per-class probabilities?
2. The training data doesn't come divided in such nice disjoint ranges. These ranges may overlap. Some text is (manually) classified for a 10-12 range, some other, from a different source, is classified as 11-13, or 8-13, etc. How would you deal with this? Modify the filtering / training? Not modify them, but interpret results differently?

Answer (score 1):

You could try doing regression instead of classification -- basically you'd try to predict the "ideal" age for reading each document.

This would allow you to deal with different age ranges, although it's not entirely clear how to represent the classes -- maybe just start by taking the average, so for 8-12, the correct answer would be 10 etc (and play around with the value for "adult" a bit).

My guess is that it could lead to a more robust estimation of the model and the results could be nicely interpretable -- e.g. if you have a lot of examples for 8-12 and 12-15 and the algorithm predicts 11.9, you could say that this is "just barely" understandable for the 8-12 range.

Comment: Thanks @ales_t. Do I understand correctly that regression predicts the value of a continuous variable? If so, is it also possible to obtain the probability (or confidence) of such predictions? If I wanted to stick with categorical variables, would it be a good idea to use logistic regression?